# How to - multiple polylines with different colors for each polyline- react-leaflet

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm building a small react app with Leaflet and React for showing different metro stations for Vienna.

The problem I came to was how to edit the colors for individual metro lines in react-leaflet. [Image of the map with different metro lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kuPw.png)
Now they are all in red, I would like to customize the colors with the colors of the circles.

The colors, name and the coordinates of each metro station are edited in the GeoJSON file.

GeoJSON file (***vienna_metro_lines_byLines.geojson***)

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",      

  "features": [
    { "type": "Feature", "id": "01", "properties": { "name": "U1", "color": "red" },
      "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates":
        [
          [ 48.1423652, 16.3999045 ], [ 48.1458145, 16.3856390 ], [ 48.1537071, 16.3824464 ], 
        ]
      }
    },
    { "type": "Feature", "id": "02", "properties": { "name": "U2", "color": "#9933ff" },
      "geometry": { "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates":
        [
          [ 48.2262470, 16.5084951 ], [ 48.2345713, 16.5044830 ], [ 48.2334553, 16.4854766 ],
        ]
 }
```

Component file

```
//data
import geojsonDataByLines from './vienna_metro_lines_byLines.geojson';

//main component
class ViennaPoliLynes extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        geojsonDataByLines: geojsonDataByLines

    };
  }

  polylineLineMaker() {
    const geojsonDataByLines = this.state.geojsonDataByLines;

    const testMe = geojsonDataByLines.features.map((cord) => {
        return cord.geometry.coordinates;
    });
    return testMe;
  }

  polylineLineColor() {
    //The color for the polylines shoud go here 
    const geojsonDataByLines = this.state.geojsonDataByLines;

    const testMe = geojsonDataByLines.features.map((cord) => {
        return cord.properties.color;
    });
    console.log(testMe)
    return testMe;    
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <Polyline positions={this.polylineLineMaker()} color={this.polylineLineColor()}>

        </Polyline>
    );
  }
}
```

Ty. For your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are actually creating just one polyline by merging the coordinates of all polylines together.  You should try rendering multiple polylines like so:

```
import {Map, Polyline} from 'react-leaflet'

//data
import geojsonDataByLines from './vienna_metro_lines_byLines.geojson';

//main component
class ViennaPoliLynes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Map>
        {geojsonDataByLines.features.map((feature) => (
          <Polyline 
            positions={feature.geometry.coordinates} 
            color={feature.properties.color}
            />
        )}
      </Map>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Chaneged my last comment. This is it. TY